# Azure App Configuration Push refresh in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, push-notification, azure-app-configuration

I have a spring boot api integrated with the Azure App Configuration service, it is working properly using Pull refresh.
I’m trying to configure it using Push Refresh using an Event Grid with WebHook. The webhook endpoint have to be configured using this url https://host/actuator/appconfiguration-refresh/tokenname=tokensecret

Before enabling the event grid I’m trying to understand how the refresh endpoint works and it is not clear to me where to find the token name and secret.
In the Microsoft documentation I read that they has to be defined into the app configuration as keys, I tried but still the post request to the actuator returns a 403.

Did anyone achieve the same scenario?

Thanks in advance.
OaicStef

Answer (score 1):

The full documentation for setting up Push Refresh can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/app-configuration-support?tabs=azure-ad#push-based-refresh. If you look at the Setting Up Web Hooks section you will see a link to the documentation you need, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery.

Web Hooks can only be setup against a live endpoint. The above link give you some ways to do this.

As for the token name and secret, it is a configuration that you provide along with your method to connect to app configuration. If you look at the first link `spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].monitoring.push-notification.primary-token.name` is shown as how you set your token name.